# How can design search engine that can query very fast?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, database-design

Im designing an architecture of search engine according to condition base search.
Each record contains multiple columns which can be, string, number, date... And I want to query records as fast as possible using queries that are condition based. (a client will query to view current records according to his filter/query)
For example:
query = (record.date > sysdate - 5 AND record.name like '%TEST%') OR (record.priority > 2 AND record.date > sysdate -2)...

What is the best way to do it?

I thought about using elasticsearch but will it be fast enough for the client?
It should be noted that the system is dynamic and records are always change, added and removed. Also, there are a lot of records stored in the system.

Comment: How much were you planning to spend to make this happen?  $100,000? One million?  More?  The amount you spend will make a difference as to what solutions we can suggest.

Comment: Can u suggest the best solution u can think about? @Gilbert Le Blanc

Comment: The environment can be a distributed system, but not large as google, i guess 5 servers is ok.. i want to support db with 10 million records, and several different queries, about 300.

Comment: Then you're going to have to do what Google does.  Create one master database that no user sees, and replicate it to your five servers.  You can continually update your master database, and replicate it on a schedule so your users understand how old the data in their copies of the database are.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc but it wasnt the question, the question was how i make the query fast? if the query condition is complex (with a lot of like '%%' for example) the user will notice it..

Comment: [Elasticsearch Queries, or Term Queries are Really Fast!](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-queries-or-term-queries-are-really-fast).  Decide for yourself.

Comment: So i was right that using elasticsearch will be a good idea? The alternative is to use scheduler that query all the items and store them in a index table, recordid, queryid. What do u think is a better idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on the post and comments, I think Elasticsearch will work well for this

how to make it fast?
make sure your mappings and queries are optimised
provide adequate hardware resources for the cluster
monitor your cluster and queries